# How to use \addtogroup with an ALIASES command?

Tags: doxygen, aliases, doxygen-addtogroup

I'm trying to create a custom command for easier group handling. The idea is in general...

```
ALIASES += opengroup{1}="^^* \addtogroup \1_GROUP ^^ * \{ ^^"
ALIASES += close="\}"
```

...to use in code file as...

```
/** \opengroup{LEVEL_1} */
// ...code statements...
/** \close */ // opengroup
```

...to get the doxygen result comment:

```
/**
* \addtogroup LEVEL_1_GROUP
* \{
*/
// ...code statements...
/** \} */ // opengroup
```

I tried with Doxygen 1.8.14. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I think the root problem is the \addtogroup command with its syntax. My hope was to clear this with inserting '^^' to force a new line, but it seems to me doxygen is parsing the command in one line instead of resolving the '^^' new line in a pre-step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit weird. With the alias:

```
ALIASES += opengroup{1}="^^* \addtogroup \1_GROUP ^^ * \\{ ^^"
```

so with a double backslash (`\\`) before the curly bracket open (`{`) I got it working. 
I also get it working with:

```
ALIASES += opengroup{1}="^^* \addtogroup \1_GROUP ^^ * @{ ^^"
```

so it looks like the extra backslash is eaten at an unexpected place. The `\` and `@` should be synonyms, but as `\` is also an escape character so it is quite often tricky.

Note:

1. I used `doxygen -d commentscan` to see the replacement
2. Might change in the future as I think this might be a bug.
3. Problem is caused due to the fact that `ALIASES` can be nested and after a change the new string is seen as input. When needing a literal `{`, `}` or `,` in the expanded output one has to escape them with a `\` and the `\` is removed at the en. Problem here arises with the commands `\{` and `\}` as here the `\` serves as 'command indicator'. Best to use `@{` and `@}` in case the 'block commands' are needed. the `\}` in `\close` doesn't have the problem as it is not re-evaluated.